# Image upload to DropBox server via it's core api giver error in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, web-services, dropbox-api

I am using DropBox core api OAuth 2.0 authentication and I am trying to upload UIImage via it's core api

https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files//

found at https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs   ( /files (POST) )

my code is

```
-(void)uploadData:(NSData *)imageAsData and:(NSString *)fileName{

NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files/dropbox/Apps?access_token=%@",dropBoxToken];


NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];


NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];


NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: attachment; name=\"attachement\"; filename=\"%@\";",fileName] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageAsData]];
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];




NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"returnString=%@",returnString);
```

where imageAsData in NSData of a image and fileName is "abc.jpg".

output of returnString is     {"error": "file parameter value 'None' is invalid"}

I don't know why this problem occurs please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, save yourself a lot of trouble and use the far simpler [`files_put`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#files_put) endpoint instead. (There's a reason it's recommended in the documentation.)

Rough editing of your code (untested):

```
-(void)uploadData:(NSData *)imageAsData and:(NSString *)filePath {

    NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:
        @"https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files_put/dropbox/%@?access_token=%@",
        filePath, dropBoxToken];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];

    [request setHTTPBody:imageAsData];

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"returnString=%@",returnString);
}
```